# Customizing disconnect event of socket.io

Tags: php, node.js, yii, redis, socket.io

i have a notification system based on socket, redis pub/sub and node running on LAMP stack ( YII framework )  and  am facing a problem. Once user logs in, on every page refresh, socket-io fires a "disconnect" event.

Is there any way to pass logged in status from PHP to socket that user is logged in and so disconnect event should not be fired on a page refresh ? At the same time, when network is disconnected, then default behavior of socket should remain as it is.

Comment: Is there any reason a custom event (i.e., 'user:loggedout') wouldn't work for your use case?

Answer (score 1):

The `disconnect` event is a base-level notification: it's fired every time the socket connection is broken, and refreshing a page breaks a connection in the same way as closing a browser window would. You can pass session information between Yii and socket.io, but that would need to happen on the `connect` event. Perhaps you should listen to a custom event?

Comment: i need to check this and will reply how it went